# How to fix the nodes position in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I have recently started to work with Networkx in python. I have a code which generates a network and based on some processes the nodes features changes. for example the colours and the statuses. for drawing the graph I use the following function

```
def draw_graph():
    colors = []
    for i in range (nCount):
        for j in range (i,nCount):
            if ifActive(i,j,timeStep) == 1 :
                
                    colors.append('r')
                  
                
            else :
                colors.append('g')
    color_map = []   
    nColor= nx.get_node_attributes(graph,'color')
    for nc in nColor:
        color_map.append(nColor[nc])   
    nx.draw(graph,pos=nx.spring_layout(graph), node_color = color_map, edge_color = colors,with_labels = True )
```

and in the main function in a for loop, I call the drawing function, but every time the position of nodes changes. Now I want to know, is there any solution to fix the position of nodes in all drawings? If yes, how I can do it?
this is the main function

```
draw_graph()
for time in range(1,timeStep+1):
         if graph.node[i]["status"] == 1:
                settime(time,i)
        plt.figure(figsize=[10, 10], dpi=50)
        draw_graph()
```

the following figure is an example of output. IF you consider the nodes based on their labels, the position of them is not fix.
[image]

Comment: NetworkX has objects [layouts](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/drawing/layout.html) which decide how to organize it but I don't know if you can use it somehow to keep layout. Maybe if you get all positions, and will assing them back after every update then you get all in the same place.

Comment: do you know how can get the position of nodes?

Comment: in current code you create positions using `nx.spring_layout(graph)` (see `pos=...`)and you could assing it to variable and later use this variable instread `nx.spring_layout(graph)` to use the same values.

Answer (score 2):

As @furas stated in the comments, in order to always obtain the same node positions you need to keep this as a variable, e.g:

```py
pos = nx.spring_layout(graph)
```

and then draw your graph as:

```py
def draw_graph(p):
    # any code here, as long as no further nodes are added.
    nx.draw(graph,pos=p)
```

Then you can finally call it as:

```py
pos = nx.spring_layout(graph)
draw_graph(pos)
# any code here, as long as no further nodes are added.
draw_graph(pos)
# each call will give the same positions.
```